# HOw to insert parameter inside json url angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to add a parameter in my url but I don't know how to do it

**ts.file**

```
route(name:string) {
 this.router.navigate(['/homepage', (name)]);
 console.log('name);
}
```

**service**

```
private url1 = './assets/json/one/first.json'

constructor(private http: HttpCient) {}

get(): Observable<Itoto[]> {
return this.http.get<Itoto[]>(this.url1);
}

getRoute() {
 this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  this.result = params.get('toto'); // i need add toto inside the url like './assets/json/toto/first.json'
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the link between your `ts.file` and your `service` ? Why is there `()` around the `name` parameter in your `route` function ?

Comment: Looks like you need to "replace" `one` with `toto` rather than "insert" the parameter. The two actions are quite different and require different actions. Someone searching for how to insert a parameter into a URL will be very disappointed with an answer that replaces part of a URL. Please [edit] your question to be more precise in what you need done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**service**

```js
private url1 = './assets/json/one/first.json'

getRoute() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.result = this.url1.replace("/one/", "/toto/"); // i need add toto inside the url like './assets/json/toto/first.json'
    }
}
```